# Best design (between two options) of unload function for CS50 speller (in C)

Tags: c, cs50

The program loads a dictionary into a linked list hash table. Unload function is supposed to free the memory.
Before the function we have this:

```
node *table[N];
```

My unload function is as follows:

```
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while (table[i] != 0) 
        {
            node *temp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It seems to work fine and doesn't give any memory leaks with valgrind. But it is designed in a different way than the walkthrough of the problem advises us to do. The walkthrough suggests to use two temporary pointers (tmp and cursor) to traverse through the list. Something like this (found this solution online):

```
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *head = table[i];
        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *tmp = head;
        while (cursor != 0)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = cursor;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So my question for the learning purposes: Is there any problem with my solution? Is the second version better? Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not much difference. However, note your version writes to `table[i]`. Nominally, that requires writing to memory. If the compiler has built-in knowledge about what `free` does, it knows that `free` does not care what is in `table[i]`, so the compiler may not actually write to the memory of `table[i]`—it will eliminate that during optimization. But, if this code call some other routines, the compiler might have to keep the write to `table[i]` even if it were not actually needed, simply because the compiler could not know whether it were needed or not.

Comment: For reasons like this, it is preferable to use temporary variables, declared just inside the scope where they are used, so the compiler can see they are not accessed by anything outside the visible code. That enables the compilers to know it is allowed to do all the work with them in registers, without actually writing anything to memory.

Comment: The other code you show uses such temporary variables. But it declares more than it needs; the work can be done entirely with two. That should not cause any more work in the optimized code the compiler generates, but it increases the burden on readers to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your solution, it is actually superior to the other one as it resets the hash table to an empty state.

Here is an alternative with fewer memory writes:

```
bool unload(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *temp = table[i];
        if (temp != NULL) {
            table[i] = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                node *next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                temp = next;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```